# What is the purpose of "casting" the return from a Boolean operator?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

From [underscore](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js):

```
  _.isElement = function(obj) {
    return !!(obj && obj.nodeType === 1);
  };
```

What is the purpose of `!!`.  It thought the result of an and statement was always true or false.

I've seen this used as way to "cast" to a Boolean type.

But I would not think it is not necessary here.

Comment: ... this has been answered below ... found reference too ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!!` trick ensures the output is true *or* false.

The expression `obj && ..` will result in the value of obj when obj evaluates to a false-y value (such as "" or 0).

Sometimes the input objects are not relevant to the result and this "casting" (it's not casting at all, but rather a coercion) cleans up the API and avoids leaking details - it can be assured that *only* true or false is returned.

Here is the TTL for `a && b`, note the result is *not necessarily* true or false:

```
a         b        a && b
-------   ------   ------
TRUTH-y   ANY      b
FALSE-Y   ANY      a
```

Here is the TTL for `!e`, the result is always true or false:

```
e         !e       !!e
-------   ------   ------
TRUTH-y   false    true
FALSE-y   true     false
```

An alternative way to express the original expression, which I actually use often:

```
return obj ? obj.nodeType === 1 : false;
```

Comment: @user2256674 -- ah, you did see my comment, I deleted it hoping you didn't see it :) oh well (I asked about something in his answer that he has since fixed)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if `obj` is eeither 0, NaN, null, undefined or an empty string, the expression will evaluate to that, not to `false`. If you need to make sure an explicit boolean variable as returned, then you have to cast.

Comment: That's not correct. If `obj` is truthy then the result of the expression is whatever `obj.nodeType === 1` evaluates to which is a boolean, as `===` always evaluates to a boolean. The `!!` is only needed here in the case that `obj` is falsy.